# How to set height of items in droplist CComboBox

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I am trying to set height for each item present in `CComboBox` drop list. I have setitemheight API but it is not changing height of each item in list. I have used `SetFont` as well but no automatic resizing either.
[image: check image for issue with height]

Comment: Did you try `SetItemHeight`?

Comment: To have variable height items you must set the `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` style and be prepared to respond to `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems like I have overridden DrawItem , hence I have made minor change there to fix issue:

```
GetLBText(lpDrawItemStruct->itemID, strText);
lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.bottom += 2;  // this solved my problem
dc.ExtTextOutW(
                lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.left,
                lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.top,
                ETO_OPAQUE,
                &lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem,
                strText,
                strText.GetLength(),
                NULL
                );
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.